# Column alias in `ORDER BY` expression?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

In Oracle 12.1.0.2 and Oracle 19c, this query:

```
with test_data (c1, c2) AS (
SELECT 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 3 FROM DUAL )
SELECT c1, c2*-1 c2
FROM test_data
order by c2*-1;
```

Returns:

> ```
> +----+----+
> | C1 | C2 |
> +----+----+
> | A  | -1 |
> | B  | -2 |
> | C  | -3 |
> +----+----+
> ```

In other words, the `c2` in `ORDER BY c2*-1` referring to the `c2` column alias in the SELECT list and NOT the `c2` column in the database table.

My reading of the *Oracle SQL Reference Guide* makes me think that the query result above is incorrect and that it is not appropriate for Oracle to think that an identifier in an `ORDER BY` expression refers to a column alias.

Has Oracle always behaved like this and I just never noticed?  Is there something in Oracle's documentation that indicates the results above are correct and expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2171079) seems quite clear to me:

> **expr**
>
> expr orders rows based on their value for expr. The expression is based on columns in the select list or columns in the tables, views, or materialized views in the FROM clause.

It actually references the "columns" in the select list first (by which it means aliases).

If you want the table column, use an alias:

```
order by test_data.c2 * -1
```

Comment: You're right, of course.  I think maybe I was thrown off by the fact that the railroad diagram has a separate branch for `c_alias` which does not seem to be described in the text.  I'll try to be less blind in the future. :)